# Is there other way to remove both parent table row and child table row using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have question regarding removing both table row, one is the child table row and the parent table row, How can i remove both parent and children?

**The first append is the parent table row,**

```
$("tbody#tbody_noun_chaining_order").
append("<tr class='editCondiments' style='background-color:'black !important',color:'white !important' '><td></td><td>"+menu_name+"</td><td>"+menu_price+"</td><td><button class='removeorderWithCondi btn btn-danger form-control'><i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></button></td></tr>");
```

**So now after inserting the parent table row, there is a child table (I called this as Condiments in the product)**

```
 $("tbody#tbody_noun_chaining_order").
   append("<tr class='editCondiments'>\
   <td class='condiments_order_quantity'>"+Qty+"</td>\
   <td>*"+Condiments+"</td><td class='total'>"+Price+"</td>\
   <td class='allow_to_open_condiments_conditional' style='display:none;'>"+allow_to_open_condiments+"</td>\
   <td class='condi_section_id' style='display:none;'>"+condiments_section_id+"</td>\
   </tr>");
```

The Output like this.

[image]

**In my onClick button remove**

```
$('button.removeorderWithCondi').click(function(){

   $(this).parent().parent().remove();

});
```

**The whole function (Inserting and Appending in the table)**

```
$("tr#productClicked").click(function () {

      var menu_name = $(this).closest("tr").find(".menu_name").text();
      var menu_price = $(this).closest("tr").find(".menu_price").text();
      var chain_id =  $(this).closest("tr").find(".chain_id").text();
      var menu_image = $(this).closest("tr").find(".menu_image").attr('src');



      swal({
      title: "Are you sure to add " + menu_name + " ?",
      text: "Once you will add it will automatically send to the cart",
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: true,
      dangerMode: true,
    })
    .then((willInsert) => {
      if (willInsert) {
        swal("Successfully Added to your form.", {
          icon: "success",
        });

       $('.append_customer_price_order').show();

       // $('.append_customer_noun_order').append(menu_name);
       // $('.append_customer_price_order').append(menu_price);

       if(chain_id == 0) {

           $("tbody#tbody_noun_chaining_order").
              append("<tr class='editCondiments' style='background-color:'black !important',color:'white !important' '><td></td><td>"+menu_name+"</td><td>"+menu_price+"</td><td><button class='removeorderWithOutCondi btn btn-danger form-control'><i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></button></td></tr>");
       }
       else
       {
          $.ajax({
            url:'/get_noun_group_combination',
            type:'get',
            data:{chain_id:chain_id},
            success:function(response){



               var noun_chaining = response[0].noun_chaining;

               $("tbody#tbody_noun_chaining_order").
              append("<tr class='editCondiments' style='background-color:'black !important',color:'white !important' '><td></td><td>"+menu_name+"</td><td>"+menu_price+"</td><td><button class='removeorderWithCondi btn btn-danger form-control'><i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></button></td></tr>");

               $.each(noun_chaining, function (index, el) {

                var stringify_noun_chaining = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(el));

                // console.log(stringify['menu_cat_image']);
                var Qty = stringify_noun_chaining['Qty'];
                var Condiments = stringify_noun_chaining['Condiments'];
                var Price = stringify_noun_chaining['Price'];
                var allow_to_open_condiments = stringify_noun_chaining['allow_to_open_condiments'];

                var condiments_section_id = stringify_noun_chaining['condiments_section_id'];


                 $("tbody#tbody_noun_chaining_order").
                append("<tr class='editCondiments'>\
                <td class='condiments_order_quantity'>"+Qty+"</td>\
                <td>*"+Condiments+"</td><td class='total'>"+Price+"</td>\
                <td class='allow_to_open_condiments_conditional' style='display:none;'>"+allow_to_open_condiments+"</td>\
                <td class='condi_section_id' style='display:none;'>"+condiments_section_id+"</td>\
                </tr>");


              })


               $('button.removeorderWithCondi').click(function(){

                $(this).parent().parent().remove();

              });




            },
            error:function(response){
              console.log(response);
            }
          });
       }


      $('.tbody_noun_chaining_order').html('');

    }
  });

});
```

Comment: if you remove the parent, then there is no child to remove, since children are removed with the parent ... are you sure `parent` and `child` accurately describe your intentions though?

Comment: @JaromandaX He's not talking about DOM parent/child relationships. They're separate rows in the table, in a master/detail relationship.

Comment: Yah, as I click the button only the parent is remove by it self, So what I want to achieve for this, If I remove the parent items the children items will be also, I will share the whole function here in my new update.

Comment: @Barmar ... `rows in a table` - oh, right ... poor terminology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the parent a distinct class, e.g. `condimentParent`. Then you can use jQuery's `nextUntil()` method to get all the rows between the current parent and the next parent.

```
$('button.removeorderWithCondi').click(function(){
    $parent = $(this).closest(".condimentParent");
    $parent.add($parent.nextUntil(".condimentParent")).remove();
});
```

Comment: Hi @Barmar, so in my table row i will add a class of condimentParent?

Comment: <tr class='editCondiments condimentParent'></tr> I look like this?

Comment: yah thanks solved my problem, How great thanks Barmar

Answer (score 0):

To solved the problem, I use the nextUntil expression of Jquery

This is the answer.

```
$("tbody#tbody_noun_chaining_order").
append("<tr class='editCondiments condimentParent' style='background-color:'black !important',color:'white !important' '><td></td><td>"+menu_name+"</td><td>"+menu_price+"</td><td><button class='removeorderWithCondi btn btn-danger form-control'><i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></button></td></tr>");
```